# Microsoft Office 2007 OEM CD With Retail Version Product Key

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

Will a Microsoft Office 2007 OEM CD recognize a retail version product key?

Comment: This is also usually true of the OS disks as well.  WinXP has two flavours of CD's floating around. The OEM and the other one.  Need the right key to use each CD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  You'll need a Retail CD for the installation to be successful.

Comment: Correct answer.

Comment: Dang! That's the fastest five responses I've ever seen on this site so far!

Answer (score 2):

No, I've never found that to work with any Microsoft products (in the last 9 years or so).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has always been very strict with their licensing keys.  I haven't tried it with 2007, but I **Highly** doubt it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I just grabbed an Office 2007 Dell OEM disc, and plugged in my Retail Office Ultimate key and it was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

And, for the third time... Nope

Answer (score 0):

It might be risky but you can probably find a torrent download of the Office 2007 retail disk.  Be careful.  Or ask around to your sysadmin friends in your area to see if anyone has one.

Comment: Hmm don't know if this deserved a - vote. It *sounds* dodgey, but he clearly has a valid license key...

Comment: Absolutely. I'm not telling him to pirate the software, he just needs a disk. My only concern is making sure you get an actual Office disk and not some garbage spyware program.